# Xcode Library Broken with Xcode 5.1 - "Assertion failed"

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcode5.1

Since updating to Xcode 5.1, I started receiving an issue:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/User/Dropbox/Apps/MyApplication/Frameworks/Project.framework/Project, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/User/Dropbox/Apps/MyApplication/Frameworks/Project.framework/Project (3 slices)
```

I tried recompiling my framework, "`Project`", but I'm now receiving an error upon execution of the run script. I'll add the run script below, but here is the error:

```
Ld /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectFramework-amlfgqgbrymfibbrhnqkcgwjkedv/Build/Intermediates/ProjectFramework.build/Release-iphoneos/Project.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Project normal arm64
    cd "/Users/User/Dropbox/VRG - IP/Frameworks/ProjectFramework"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -r -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectFramework-amlfgqgbrymfibbrhnqkcgwjkedv/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectFramework-amlfgqgbrymfibbrhnqkcgwjkedv/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectFramework-amlfgqgbrymfibbrhnqkcgwjkedv/Build/Intermediates/ProjectFramework.build/Release-iphoneos/Project.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Project.LinkFileList -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/lib/dylib1.o -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectFramework-amlfgqgbrymfibbrhnqkcgwjkedv/Build/Intermediates/ProjectFramework.build/Release-iphoneos/Project.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Project_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectFramework-amlfgqgbrymfibbrhnqkcgwjkedv/Build/Intermediates/ProjectFramework.build/Release-iphoneos/Project.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Project

ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//UIKit.framework/UIKit) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//Foundation.framework/Foundation) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib) on link line
ld: warning: unexpected dylib (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib) on link line
0  0x1034edf93  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x10355774a  ld::Atom::setSectionStartAddress(unsigned long long) + 0
2  0x103546e6c  ld::tool::SectionRelocationsAtom<arm64>::encodeSectionReloc(ld::Internal::FinalSection*, ld::tool::SectionRelocationsAtom<arm64>::Entry const&, std::__1::vector<macho_relocation_info<Pointer64<LittleEndian> >, std::__1::allocator<macho_relocation_info<Pointer64<LittleEndian> > > >&) + 84
3  0x10356d7ec  ld::tool::SectionRelocationsAtom<arm64>::encode() + 62
4  0x10354cc82  ld::tool::OutputFile::updateLINKEDITAddresses(ld::Internal&) + 454
5  0x103547968  ld::tool::OutputFile::write(ld::Internal&) + 138
6  0x1034eec40  main + 1012
A linker snapshot was created at:
    /tmp/Project-2014-02-11-125437.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (_machoSection != 0), function machoSection, file /SourceCache/ld64/ld64-236.3/src/ld/ld.hpp, line 714.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is the run script ([referenced from this tutorial](http://simplyitinc.blogspot.ca/2011/04/creating-static-framework-in-xcode-4.html)):

```
# Sets the target folders and the final framework product.
FMK_NAME=VRGViews
FMK_VERSION=A

# Install dir will be the final output to the framework.
# The following line create it in the root folder of the current project.
INSTALL_DIR=${SRCROOT}/Products/${FMK_NAME}.framework

# Working dir will be deleted after the framework creation.
WRK_DIR=build
DEVICE_DIR=${WRK_DIR}/Release-iphoneos/${FMK_NAME}.framework
SIMULATOR_DIR=${WRK_DIR}/Release-iphonesimulator/${FMK_NAME}.framework

# Building both architectures.
xcodebuild -configuration "Release" -target "${FMK_NAME}" -sdk iphoneos
xcodebuild -configuration "Release" -target "${FMK_NAME}" -sdk iphonesimulator

# Cleaning the oldest.
if [ -d "${INSTALL_DIR}" ]
then
rm -rf "${INSTALL_DIR}"
fi

# Creates and renews the final product folder.
mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}"
mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions"
mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}"
mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/Resources"
mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/Headers"

# Creates the internal links.
# It MUST uses relative path, otherwise will not work when the folder is copied/moved.
ln -s "${FMK_VERSION}" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/Current"
ln -s "Versions/Current/Headers" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Headers"
ln -s "Versions/Current/Resources" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Resources"
ln -s "Versions/Current/${FMK_NAME}" "${INSTALL_DIR}/${FMK_NAME}"

# Copies the headers and resources files to the final product folder.
cp -R "${DEVICE_DIR}/Headers/" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/Headers/"
cp -R "${DEVICE_DIR}/" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/Resources/"

# Removes the binary and header from the resources folder.
rm -r "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/Resources/Headers" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/Resources/${FMK_NAME}"

# Uses the Lipo Tool to merge both binary files (i386 + armv6/armv7) into one Universal final product.
lipo -create "${DEVICE_DIR}/${FMK_NAME}" "${SIMULATOR_DIR}/${FMK_NAME}" -output "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/${FMK_NAME}"

rm -r "${WRK_DIR}"
```

Comment: Do you keep XCode projects in dropbox? *Yikes*.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems you only need to **change your MACH-O to Static Library from Relocatable Object File**. All should be OK.
As an example you can see GPUImage framework project settings and its build script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

IOSSDK_VER="7.0"

# xcodebuild -showsdks

cd framework
xcodebuild -project GPUImage.xcodeproj -target GPUImage -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos${IOSSDK_VER} build
xcodebuild -project GPUImage.xcodeproj -target GPUImage -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator${IOSSDK_VER} build
cd ..

cd build
# for the fat lib file
mkdir -p Release-iphone/lib
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -create Release-iphoneos/libGPUImage.a Release-iphonesimulator/libGPUImage.a -output Release-iphone/lib/libGPUImage.a
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info Release-iphone/lib/libGPUImage.a
# for header files
mkdir -p Release-iphone/include
cp ../framework/Source/*.h Release-iphone/include
cp ../framework/Source/iOS/*.h Release-iphone/include

# Build static framework
mkdir -p GPUImage.framework/Versions/A
cp Release-iphone/lib/libGPUImage.a GPUImage.framework/Versions/A/GPUImage
mkdir -p GPUImage.framework/Versions/A/Headers
cp Release-iphone/include/*.h GPUImage.framework/Versions/A/Headers
ln -sfh A GPUImage.framework/Versions/Current
ln -sfh Versions/Current/GPUImage GPUImage.framework/GPUImage
ln -sfh Versions/Current/Headers GPUImage.framework/Headers
```

Comment: Are you sure that will work without fail? Changing the MACH-O type isn't a very minor change.

Comment: All seems to be OK ;)